Datastream - AWS AURORA MySQL to BigQuery
I'm trying to stream/migrate data from AWS aurora mysql to BigQuery. By following this documentation Create an HA VPN gateway to a peer VPN gateway I able to ping private and public subnet vice versa - via instances/vm.
The problem is on the Datastream. Here's the configuration profile

Connection Details
host or IP: aws_cluster_endpoint
port: 3306
username: DB_USER
password: DB_PASSWORD
encryption type: none
connectivity method: Private Connectivity (VPC Peering)

the testing result:
Test failed We timed out trying to connect to the data source. Make sure that the hostname and port configuration is correct, and that the data source is available.
I tried this documentation to get a certificate/SSL
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html
to put it on the encryption type, but still not test is failed.
another I tried is this Private Connectivity still the test result is failed. I think this is within GCP environment only.


Make sure that the hostname and port configuration is correct


host or IP: aws_cluster_endpoint port: 3306

Could it be that

you mistyped during definition/configuration of aws_cluster_endpoint or a port
if aws_cluster_endpoint is a variable, then maybe you need to use it in different way (e.g. in bash instead of aws_cluster_endpoint you need to use ${aws_cluster_endpoint})

Other possible reasons:
3) Connection timed out appears because some resource is not enabled.
4) Datastream is not included in some network
5) Wrong DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD is the reason of timeout
